# How to save content of the iframe using javascript in Windows 8 store HTML5/javascript app?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have an iframe control with the source pointing to a page defined in my code. Now How to save content of the iframe using javascript in Windows 8 store app ?I tried the below code but it never goes to any of the below if conditions.

```
    var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/");
     if (ifrm.contentDocument) {
        // Firefox, Opera
        doc = ifrm.contentDocument;
    }
    else if (ifrm.contentWindow) {
        // Internet Explorer
        doc = ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    }

    else if (ifrm.document) {
        // Others?
        doc = ifrm.document;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the security changes in WWAs. You'll need to add the destination URL as a valid destination in your manifest.

Comment: Can I do adding of  the destination URL as a valid destination in manifest programmatically? Because this URL is not the only URL I use in my app.

Comment: Nope. You'll need to look at the sand boxing attributes for iframe security - these allow a little flexibility in this area.